# Apk Upload failed:Your Instant App APKs do not declare a valid 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in their AndroidManifest

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to upload a version of the instant app sample code to the market with no success. I keep getting the following error:

> Your Instant App APKs do not declare a valid
>   'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in their AndroidManifest

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

What 'vyndor' says is correct.  The AndroidManifest.xml file that needs to include it is the one for the "base" feature.

If you use Android Studio 3.0 Canary 4, the android:targetSandboxVersion attribute should be set for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Target API 25.
2. Add `android:targetSandboxVersion="2"` to your AndroidManifest `<manifest>` tag.

Comment: There is no such attribute

Comment: Update your sdk to the latest version.

Comment: I have Target API 26 still I am getting same error. Even after putting `android:targetSandboxVersion="2"` in features AndroidManifest getting same error.

Comment: There are several manifest files. What manifest do you modify?