# Your Instant App APKs do not declare a valid

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Am having a bad time with android in order to create new release

i have created a Signed APK with two option

[image]

then i zipped the .apk file,after trying to upload it to google console am getting the below error

[image]

> Your Instant App APKs do not declare a valid 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in their AndroidManifest. Using the 'com.android.feature' Gradle plugin to build your Instant App would add this attribute automatically.

Note : the file zipped and all the solutions asking to zip the file, no luck :(

Comment: Did you zip the apk file and then tried to upload? `the file zipped and all the solutions asking to zip the file` - did not quite understand what you were saying there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apk Upload failed:Your Instant App APKs do not declare a valid 'android:targetSandboxVersion' attribute in their AndroidManifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44498364/apk-upload-failedyour-instant-app-apks-do-not-declare-a-valid-androidtargetsa)

Comment: yes, i zip the apk then upload it, getting this msg after uploading

Comment: Please check the answer that I posted above. Do not zip the apk file. Build your apk with both V1 and V2 jar signature checked. Do these three things and please let me know if that issue is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: tried, getting this msg (Your Instant App APKs must be a '.zip' file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be clear if you are producing an [Instant App](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html) or a normal Android app. I think this is what is confusing you, or maybe you just aren't being clear in the question.

[Android Instant Apps](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/index.html) are special Android apps that launch from a web page, and don't need a user to install them. To build them you need the Instant Apps SDK, and to follow the development instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/getting-started/index.html). Android Studio will produce a zip for you, you don't need to do it manually

For normal Android apps, you don't need to zip your APKs. Just upload the APK itself to the Play Console.

I think you are probably making a normal Android app, but because you are zipping it, the Play console thinks you are uploading an instant app. So stopping Zipping your APK, and just upload it to the Play Console as a ".apk" file.

While you are at it, I'd recommend using APK V2 signing - it gives much faster installation on modern devices.

Comment: it was my mistake, what i need is to upload a production version not instant app updates, thank u